# Does IL Merge work with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework

Does anyone have experience using IL Merge and the .NET CF? Does IL Merge work with CF? Are there any known problems?

Comment: Changed your title to reflect the question. It's a bit annoying to see a meaningless title like ".net compact framework". Hard to know what it means, if it's worth reading, or if you can answer it without. Please try to write more descriptive titles in the future. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, IL merge does support the Compact Framework platform.  By default it will attempt to target the desktop CLR.  You must pass the path to the Compact framework install to the /targetplatform parameter though.

For Example

ilmerge /t:winexe /targetplatform:v2,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\Debugger\BCL"

This blog post has an excellent breakdown of this process:

http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/01/30/UsingILMergeOnCompactFrameworkApplications.aspx